# Why will $g(x)$ decrease for any interval at all?

Tags: calculus

Given: $f''(x)>0 $ and $f'(1)=0$. $g(x)=f(\cot^2x+2\cot x+2)$ for $0<x<\pi$. I need to find the interval for which $g(x)$ is decreasing.

Now, for $0<x<\pi$, $\cot^2x+2\cot x+2$ assumes all values from $[1,\infty)$. From $f''(x)>0$ and $f'(1)=0$ we know $f(x)$ is increasing for all values greater than $1$. But since the minimum input into $f(t)$ is $t=1$ (minimum value of $\cot^2x+2\cot x+2$), shouldn't this imply that $g(x)$ is increasing for all values of $x$?

The correct answer is: $g(x)$ is decreasing for $0<x<3\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: is $\cot^2x+2\cot x+2$ increasing for all $x$?

Rationale: $f$ being increasing means that it *preserves* whether its argument increases or decreases.

Comment: But why does that matter, though? $f''(x)>0 $ and $f'(1)=0$ should imply that for any t>1, f(t) is increasing

Comment: If $f(t)$ increases when $t$ increases, what happens when $t$ decreases?